# How to insert a variable inside bash -c command

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I can do the following:

```
$ FOO="text"
$ echo $FOO
$ text
```

But how can I wrap it inside `bash -c` construct? I tried this but failed:

```
$ FOO="text"
$ bash -c 'echo $FOO'
$ # return nothing
```

The reason I ask this because I need to execute another 3rd party code that need to be wrapped inside `bash -c`

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: `FOO="text"; bash -c "echo $FOO"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
$ export FOO="text"
$ bash -c 'echo $FOO'
```

> export command is used to export a variable or function to the
>   environment of all the child processes running in the current shell.

[Here's the source](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/bash-shell-builtin-commands/)

The "bash" command starts a child  process where its parent is your current bash session.

To define a variable in parent process and use it in child process, you have to export it.

Comment: `FOO=text bash -c 'echo $FOO'` would work as well - in this case, the environment variable `FOO` is set just in the context of the process (`bash`) being created.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `bash -c 'FOO=test; echo \$FOO'` 
or `export FOO=test;bash -c 'echo $FOO'`

Comment: tried that, it won't do, it returns `$FOO` instead.

Comment: export FOO="text"
bash -c 'echo $FOO'  is the right way, ignore my answer

Comment: you can also use bash -c '$FOO=test;echo \$FOO', i always do like this

Comment: @ceilKs update your answer so as to help others that may seek the same assistance

Comment: Sorry but the left part of condition doesn't met the requirement.